# Slow localhost Drupal websites and drush

Tags: configuration

I installed XAMPP on a new laptop to use it for Drupal. All the websites on my localhost are extremely slow, even a brand new vanilla Drupal website. It takes 5-10 seconds to go from one page to the other with a message at the bottom left corner of "Waiting for localhost".

I tried a lot of configuration adjustments but nothing worked. Things like:

- disabled XDEBUG
- enabled Opcache
- increased/modified php.ini settings:

  - memory_limit, max_execution_time etc...
- increased/modified my.cnf settings:

  - max_connections, wait_timeout, innodb_ etc...
- edited the 'hosts' file found here: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc by uncommenting # 127.0.0.1 localhost
- turned off the Firewall etc..

and a lot of other things that i didnt document...

DRUSH cc all also takes like 1 minute.

When navigating between pages of a local drupal website, the mysqld.exe service goes all the way to 3Mb/s and usage of over 95% in the Task Manager.

i feel that it's a mysql issue, not an apache but at this point im not sure anymore.

Does anyone have other ideas?

Comment: It's likely database cache. A memory cache would resolve most of this.

Comment: Kevin, It sounds like you've had to deal with this before: how would i go about fixing this issue with a memory cache?

Comment: You'd have to add and enable either memcache or redis. Check the module pages for more details

Comment: "Does anyone have other ideas?" If you are willing to spend time in optimizing your local hosting use some kind of virtualization and build it more production-like, you probably won't run your website on a client windows pc. Look for a virtual machine or docker based solution in the offical docs https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/local-server-setup

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD/NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
Use this url for Windows version of software  https://github.com/pmachapman
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @Nathan When you want suggestions for MySQL improvement, please post data requested Dec 27, 2019.